# Why was no action found for route?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My WebApiConfig.cs contains just this one route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Calendar",
    routeTemplate: "api/Calendar/{date}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Calendar", action = "Get", date = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And my CalendarController class has only this method:

```
public IEnumerable<FVEvent> Get( string dateStr )
{
    return db.Events.ToList();
}
```

But when I try hitting /api/Calendar in the browser, I get the following MessageDetail in the XML:

```
No action was found on the controller 'Calendar' that matches the request.
```

Plus I don't know why it's XML, I'd like it to be JSON.

There's just so much hidden magic going on I can't make a slight adjustment to a simple example without everything falling apart.

Comment: What's the name of your `Controller` class? All `Controller` clases must end with `Controller`

Comment: Yup, it's called CalendarController.

Comment: You don't need to specify a default value for `Calendar` part as it's not optional. Otherwise, try changing the `routeTemplate` to routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{date}",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route marks the dateStr parameter as optional, but the method signature does not. Try adding a default value to your dateStr parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<FVEvent> Get(string dateStr = "")
{
    return db.Events.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of your Calendar Controller ends with `Controller`. Also use the following code in your WebAPI config to remove the XML formatter.

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```